# Add X number to previous number

Tags: javascript

i have been making a "auto bet script" to one site, the script is done but i have some issues with "Statics" that i want to add there. So i get a X value every round, lets say that i get number 5.2 it should save it for next round so i can add the 5.2 to next round number, so lets say round 2 number is 7.2 so it should remember the 5.2 from previous round and add 7.2 to it, and then 3 round it should add X number to the 12.4 (that comes from 5.2 + 7.2)

Here is my code

```
$('#case_test').click( function(){

setTimeout(function(){


$('#case_item_win .case_item_name br').remove();
var name = $('#case_item_win .case_item_name').text().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
console.log('%cCase number: #' + nb , 'color:#C585DE; font-size:15px;');
console.log('%cName: ' + name.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""), 'color: #FF0000; font-size:15px');
console.log('%cWear: ' + $('#case_item_win .case_item_wear').text(), 'color: #036CFF; font-size:15px');
console.log('%cPrice: ' + $('#case_item_win .case_item_price').text(), 'color: #FF9603; font-size:15px');

caseCosts = $('.case_price').text();
skinPrice = $('#case_item_win .case_item_price').text();

totalUsedtoCases = nb * caseCosts;


console.log('%c=============================================', 'color: #000;');
console.log('%cSTATICS', 'font-size:25px; text-align:center;font-weight:bold;color:cyan;');
console.log('\n');
console.log('Used to cases: $' + totalUsedtoCases + '\nAll skins: SOON \nResult: **');
console.log('%c=============================================', 'color: #000;');

}, 10000)

})

nb = 0;
interval = setInterval(function(){

$('#case_test').trigger('click');
nb += 1;

if(nb >= 100) {
clearInterval(interval);
}
}, 14000)
```

And `skinPrice = $('#case_item_win .case_item_price').text();` is the current round value/number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble parsing exactly what you're trying to do. However, you can use a closure to maintain some state between function calls with setTimeout.

```
$('#case_test').click( function(){
// you can put a variable here that will be available to the function in setTimeout across each invokation
var total = 0;
setTimeout(function(){
// every time you add or access total here, it will be kept across invokations
total += 100;
$('#case_item_win .case_item_name br').remove();
```